# Stop on first error

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic exit from bash shell script on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error)

How can I have bash stop on the first command failure, without putting stuff like this all through my code?

```
some_prog || exit 1
some_other_prog || exit 1
```

Answer (score 811, accepted):

Maybe you want `set -e`:

[www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html#id2382181](http://web.archive.org/web/20110314180918/http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html):

> This tells bash that it should exit the script if any statement returns a non-true return value. The benefit of using -e is that it prevents errors snowballing into serious issues when they could have been caught earlier. Again, for readability you may want to use set -o errexit.

Comment: Be aware of `set -e` gotchas: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @Kris Thanks, this bit me on linux mint. it silently exits script with no message. so i've removed set -e usage.

Comment: @LukeW this is normal. However, the exit code will be non-zero, indicating an error. Also any program that fails normally prints an error message by itself, try with just shebang + `set -e` + e.g. `ls nope`. You get one clear error message, and scripts fails early. Excellent software.

Comment: the linked duplicate has a good answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/362951

Comment: How do I set -e only for a portion of the script and then reset?

Comment: @Scorb use `set +e`