# jenkins does not recognize the errors when building the cpp code

Tags: c++, c, bash, build, jenkins

I am using jenkins for my CI server but i have problems when i want to build the project because jenkins does not recognize the compilation errors.This is my problem:

```
creating objects directory obj
g++ -I../src -I third-party/cppunit-1.12.1/include -fPIC -g -Wall -c booktest.cpp -o obj/booktest.o
g++ -I../src -I third-party/cppunit-1.12.1/include -fPIC -g -Wall -c reader/bookreadertest.cpp -o obj/reader/bookreadertest.o
g++ -I../src -I third-party/cppunit-1.12.1/include -fPIC -g -Wall -c indexer/indexertest.cpp -o obj/indexer/indexertest.o
indexer/indexertest.cpp: In constructor ‘IndexerTest::IndexerTest()’:
indexer/indexertest.cpp:17:12: error: ‘failMethod’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [obj/indexer/indexertest.o] Error 1
creating objects directory obj
g++ -I ../src -fPIC -g -Wall -c src/main.cpp -o obj/src/main.o
g++ -o oreallybooks -fPIC -g -Wall obj/src/main.o -L/user/local/lib -L../src/lib -loreally -lm
Finished: SUCCESS



I am using  bash files to build and clean the cpp project
I "execute shell" for "build steps" in jenkins and this is the command:

/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/OreallyBooks/workspace/buildProject

"buildProject" is bash file and contains:


!/bin/bash
cd src;
make;
cd ../test;
make;
cd ../ui
make;
```

Someone can help me please? thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything other than the final make fails then the bash script will ignore the error.

You need to set the script to fail on first error

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

[Stop on first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error)