# Stop bash script when find gets to a folder with permission denied

Tags: bash

How can I stop script when command "find" gets to a folder with permission denied.

I make a list of all folders in my PC.

I would like to stop the searching process when "find" finds a permission denied folder.

```html
DIRS=$(find . -type d)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please look at [this answered question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225572/exit-bash-when-find-gets-to-a-folder-with-permission-denied) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error).

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this now, but you should check with exec if the folder is executable.

Something like

```
find -type d -print0 -not -exec test -x '{}' \; -quit
```