# Exit status from shell scripts in npm run scripts on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, npm

I have a very simple shell script, `test.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exit 1
```

I'm calling this from my `test` run script in `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "test.sh && echo \"unexpected output\""
},
```

Running `npm test` I get this:

```
$ npm test

> testtest@1.0.0 test C:\Users\[path]\testtest
> test.sh && echo "unexpected output"

"unexpected output"
```

It seems as if npm doesn't care about the non-zero exit code of test.sh. I was not expecting to see "unexpected output".

How do I make the execution of the `"test"` command stop when one of the steps it performs (`test.sh` in this case) exits with an error?

With this in my package.json: `"test": "test.sh && echo $?",`
This is the output:

```
$ npm test

> testtest@1.0.0 test C:\Users\[path]\testtest
> test.sh && echo $?

$?
```

With this: `"test": "test.sh && echo \"$?\"",`
I get this:

```
$ npm test

> testtest@1.0.0 test C:\Users\[path]\testtest
> test.sh && echo "$?"

"$?"
```

As a sanity-check I added an echo after the exit in `test.sh`. Thankfully it doesn't print :)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exit 1

echo "This should not print"
```

The "This should not print" text never shows up in my console.

Actually, adding an `echo` before `exit 1` also doesn't print anything to my GitBash console. Instead it prints to a temporary cmd window that npm launches. So I'm guessing the exit status is lost inside that cmd session.

Comment: Can you post what happens when you replace the echo message with `echo $?` (just to make sure the exit code is correctly arriving as 1). [$? returns the exit code of the last run command](http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/).

Comment: @Squirrel I get the literal string `$?` :(

Comment: One idea would be to try set -e ([as explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error)), maybe the .sh script is not being stopped correctly by node? Also, just to make sure, your line ended up as `test.sh && echo $?`, right?

Comment: @Squirrel I updated the question with info about what I ran and the output. I also just now tried with `set -e` in test.sh. Didn't make any difference

Comment: Can you check that, if adding some `echo`s under the `exit 1` command in the .sh file, they are actually not displayed?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't print anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163709/discussion-between-squirrel-and-tobbe).

Comment: @Squirrel Just found this page, encountering the same problem, and very disappointed to find that the solution was kept to a private chat :(

Comment: @Katie No solution was ever found :(

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "bash test.sh && echo \"unexpected output\""
},
```

With the additional "bash", the script runs in the current Git Bash. The "unexpected output" is not printed.
If I omit the "bash", a new Bash window is opened, and I also get the "unexpected output".

```
$ npm test

> npm2@1.0.0 test D:\Martin\dev\npm-test\npm2
> bash test.sh && echo "unexpected output"

Hi from script! Next: exit 1
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

As a side note, if you're developing a cross-platform Node.js project, it might be better to avoid Bash/Cmd/Powershell scripts. Just use Node.js scripts instead, and you don't need additional tools to be installed.

Comment: "Just use Node.js scripts instead, and you don't need additional tools to be installed." -- I have the same problem with .js files that call `process.exit()`. How did you get it to work?

Comment: @Bbrk24 I do not have this problem (Win10, Node 12): `"scripts": { "test0": "node index.js 0 && echo \"Expected output\"", "test1": "node index.js 1 && echo \"Unexpected output\"" },`. Index.js contains: `var code = parseInt(process.argv[2]); console.log('exit ' + code); process.exit(code);`. When I run  `npm run test0`, I get "exit 0 / Expected output". When I run `npm run test1`, I only get "exit 1", as expected.