# How to exit a bash script if the c++ compiler finds an error?

Tags: c++, bash, compiler-errors, exit-code

I am using a bash script that does the following:

```
makepp

./mainHeu
```

where `makepp` is used to run a c++ code that returns the executable `./mainHeu`.
I would like to stop the bash script before `./mainHeu` if the compiler finds an error during `makepp`, so I can see the error immediately on terminal without the bash executing the earlier version of `mainHeu`.

I have been looking online for similar cases without finding any.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error - those should help

Comment: Is `makeapp` exiting with an appropriate exit status if a failure occurs inside it? Given your question you don't know about exit status so then maybe you (or someone else) haven't written `makeapp` to exit with an appropriate status and then the obvious solution wouldn't automatically work. Can you make it fail and then do `echo "$?"` and then tell us what the number that outputs is?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a [`set -e`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25_01) command at the top of the script. Then the shell will terminate whenever a command fails, whose termination status is not tested by the script. (This is not a complete, detailed description of the `set -e` mode; there are nuances).

`set -e` mode is based on the ideas that

1. any given executed in a script usually only makes sense if the previous commands have all succeeded;
2. if a command fails, it is better to terminate, than to execute further commands which assume its success. For instance if a `cd dir` command fails, subsequent commands will create, access or delete files in the wrong directory.
3. explicitly testing every command and terminating adds verbiage and noise to the script and can easily be forgotten.

That doesn't mean we can just blindly add `set -e` to scripts and expect an improvement. One problem is that it's possible for programs to succeed, yet return an unreliable termination status indication. In the C language, before the C99 standard, if the `main` function returned without a value, the termination status of the program was undefined, as in `int main(void) { }`.  Since C99, that is required to be treated as `int main(void) { return 0; }`.
Before the return zero rule, such programs could cause `set -e` scripts to unexpectedly bail.

Comment: When suggesting `set -e` it's good to also provide a reference to the bash FAQ on that subject, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 so users can understand the pros, cons, usage, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm afraid I don't agree with things in that FAQ, so I won't proliferate links to it.  Including the above idiotic diatribe (FAQ 105).

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
makepp || exit
./mainHeu
```

If you do it like this (i.e.):

```
makepp || exit 25
./mainHeu
```

you can even define your own exit code, which can be evaluated by the caller. If for instance `mainHeu` signals failure by setting exit code 1 (a common scenario), the caller can know, whether the failure came from compiling the program or from running it.