# Makefile task halt on error, can I continue run it?

Tags: bash, makefile

In my makefile there is a task to sync config files

```
redis:
    mkdir -p /var/lib/redis
    mkdir -p /var/log/redis
    useradd --system --home-dir /var/lib/redis redis
    chown redis.redis /var/lib/redis
    chown redis.redis /var/log/redis
    cp ./scripts/redis-server.d.conf /etc/init/redis-server.conf
    cp ./scripts/redis.conf /etc/redis.conf
    restart redis
```

but when I run 2nd time:

```
useradd --system --home-dir /var/lib/redis redis
useradd: user 'redis' already exists
```

as you can see, it halt on useradd, can I continue run it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have gnu make continue after error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188376/how-to-have-gnu-make-continue-after-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `useradd` command is returning an error code.

You can prepend a dash to the command as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188394/183066) (actually, I found this is a duplicated question):

```
-useradd --system --home-dir /var/lib/redis redis
```

Alternatively, a workaround to make that command always return a success code is to combine it with `true` as follows:

```
useradd --system --home-dir /var/lib/redis redis || true
```

Comment: It's slightly awkward to assume that any error from `useradd` would be because the user already exists.  A better fix would be to check if the user already exists, and only if not, attempt to create it.