# How do I make sure erroneous code does not build in a CI process?

Tags: c++, testing, makefile, continuous-integration, gnu-make

I am writing some C++ library, and I already use some CI (Continuous Integration) process, to make sure the features work.
The build is makefile-based, so the CI script holds a `make test` line. That target will run the automated tests (say, using Catch), and build passes only if it succeeds.

The good practices mandates that a wrong usage of the library by user code should preferably trigger a compile error, instead of a run-time error. So I included lots of static checking.

However, I want to make sure in my automated testing process that this is really the case (that user code using the library erroneously will fail to build).

So I put up a folder holding several .cpp files, each demonstrating an incorrect usage of the library, thus each of them should fail to build.

My problem is that if I add a new target in my makefile to build these, it will return after first failure.

What I want to do is make sure that **all** these files fail to build, and return 0 only in that case.

How can I write a target that performs this ?

Some (not working) code, that will return after first failure.

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC_FILES))

all: $(OBJ_FILES)
    @echo "done"

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $<
```

If I basically ignore the failures (prepending line with `-`), I won't be able to check that all of the files are incorrect.

Comment: Kinda related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188376/ but that question asks for a null return code if running code fails, not the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it if you want to use the same pattern rule, is through recursive make and passing the `-k` flag ([`--keep-going`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Testing.html)), like this:

```
TEST_SRCS := bad1.cpp bad2.cpp bad3.cpp

.PHONY: test_compile
test_compile:
          $(MAKE) -k $(TEST_SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
```

Another option is to compile them all in a loop in a single recipe:

```
test_compile:
         ok=true; \
         for src in $(TEST_SRCS); do \
           $(CXX) -o $${src%.cpp}.o -c $$src || ok=false; \
         done; \
         $$ok
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I'll check and try that ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
srcs := fail1.cpp fail2.cpp fail3.cpp
failed := ${srcs:.cpp=.failed}

PHONY: test
test: ${failed} ; : $@ Success

${failed}: %.failed: %.cpp
    ! gcc blah blah $< -o ${@:.failed=.o}
    touch $@
```

What happens here is that when you want to build `test`, *make* first tries to build `fail1.failed`.

If the compile succeeds, *make* fails with an error.

OTOH if the compile fails, the output file `fail1.failed` is created.

BTW, *make* knows that `fail1.failed` depends on `fail1.cpp`.
If the `.failed` is newer than the `.cpp`, the test will not even run.
Nice.

Same for `fail2.failed` and `fail3.failed`. Parallel safe, and if you get your dependencies right, only the tests that need to run get run. The whole point of *make* really.

Comment: Thanks for answer, interesting approach, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting answer form @MadScientist but for the record, seems this can be done also this way:

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC_FILES))

all: $(OBJ_FILES)
    @echo "done"

%.o: %.cpp
    ! $(CXX) -o $@ -c $<
```

Just by reversing the return value from the compile shell command: if a single file succeeds, then make will immediately exit with an "error" return value.